# Error with function MonteCarlo simulations in R

Tags: r, function, montecarlo

I am having some troubles with the following function, it does give me a result but I don't understand what it is actually doing.

I am trying to build a Dcf Model with Monte Carlo simulations, but I don't understand what it is wrong. Growth and r are both vector of 10.000 trials.

```
montecarlosimulations <- function(fcf0, growth, n, r, t0=FALSE){
  rval <- c()
  help <- c(fcf0)
  for(i in growth){
    help <- help*(1+i)
    rval <- c(rval, help)
  }
  return(rval)
  print(paste(rval))
  if(length(r)==1){
    r <- rep(r, length(reval))
    if(t0==TRUE){r[1]<-0}
  }
  for(i in r){
  PVffcf <- (rval/((1+r))^n)
  }  
  return(rval)
  print(paste(PVffcf))
  print(sum(PVffcf[1:5]))

}
```

I would like to know how the current function is working and track somehow which are all the results of all the calculations inside the function to understand what is wrong with the function.
Thank you very much!

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: 1) That is not the full function, it's missing the beginning. 2) the function `return(rval)` right after the first loop, it never reaches the rest. 3) What is `x` in `length(x)`? 4) Wrong: `if(t0==TRUE)`, right: maybe `if(isTRUE(t0))`, maybe simply `if(t0)`. 5) If `PVffcf` is character then there is no difference between `paste(PVffcf)` and `PVffcf`.

Comment: Why do you have return statements? Is this the body of a function? Please post your full code with more context.

Comment: Yes, it is missing the beginning, sorry, I just fixed it!  Because I want it to stop when all the elements of growth are finished. However I just realized, reval should be a data frame of 6 columns and 10.000 rows. Do you know how to use each element of the growth vector, to simulate a growing behavor of a variable until period n? I thing there is where I am failing.